# Error in Updating a Record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, insert-update

Hello Everyone I'm new in here. I am currently making an asp.net project monitoring module. At this moment I am in the process of editing the project form and adding resources to the selected task in a project.

I'm having a problem in saving the record. Everytime I save the record it says

> "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition."

In my ProjectTasks Table I have RefNo(PK), TaskID(FK), Name and Description

Name - refers to the Task Name

Description - refers to the Task Description

What I want to happen is that my Resource Tables TaskID(FK) will be updated when I clicked the save button. As of now when I add a Resource from a task the TaskID = 0.

---

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ProjectTasks VALUES (@Name, @Description); " +
    "SELECT TOP 1 TaskID FROM ProjectTasks ORDER BY TaskID DESC;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescription.Text);
    int taskID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Resource_Materials SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Equipments SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Vehicles SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Contractors SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", taskID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Helper.AddLog("1", "Add", "Assigned Resources to Task");
    Response.Redirect("~/Projects/Default.aspx");
}
```

---

Sorry about my grammar I'm just a student.

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: I get the error on the Insert Statement

Comment: Don't use AddWithValue() where the type has to be guessed.  Use following :             cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaskID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = taskID;

Comment: You need to supply a value for the FK if the FK column does not allow null. Also put you code in try catch block and don't open and close the connection between sequential commands.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> ProjectTasks Table I have RefNo(PK), TaskID(FK), Name and Description

In such case, your `INSERT` query should look like below instead, specify the exact column name you are trying to insert values and as well you are missing `TaskID(FK)` column in your current insert query

```
INSERT INTO ProjectTasks(TaskID, Name, Description) 
VALUES (@TaskID, @Name, @Description);
```

Comment: I've tried that but then what will happen is that it will create a new record on my ProjectTasks table instead and using its TaskID it will be assigned to my Resources Table. What I just want is to update the resources the I will be adding based on the Task I choose from the Project Form.

Comment: @Rhym, in that case just modify the insert statement to be like `INSERT INTO ProjectTasks(Name, Description) 
VALUES (@Name, @Description);`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is misleading..

Your ProjectTasks has 4 columns but you try to insert 2 column value in your insert statement without declaring them after your table name as `ProjectTasks (Name, Description)`.

But this still generate a problem because your first column is PK and second one is FK. Since FK can be null but PK can't be null as far as I know, that's why you need to re-think your inserting logic.

But even if you fix it, your code *still* has a problem. Since you set a new string to your `CommandText` property, your `@Name` and `@Description` parameters were still belongs on your `cmd` object. That's why on `ExecuteNonQuery` line, your `cmd` will have 3 parameters as `@Name`, `@Description` and `@TaskID` but your command has only 1 parameter. As you can see, you will get an error such as; *the parameter you supplied and command doesn't match* or something. In such a case, you need to [`Clear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your parameters before you set new `CommandText` or generate a new SqlCommand object as `cmd = new SqlCommand()`

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and commands automatically instead of calling `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` methods manually.

And don't use `AddWithValue` method anymore. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Answer (score 0):

In an insert statement, we need to supply the column names when we don't want to specify values for all columns. If we don't do this we need so supply values for all columns.
In your case, you just want to provide values for Name and Description so you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO ProjectTasks(Name, Description) VALUES (@Name, @Description);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing ExecuteScalar and by replacing INSERT statement into UPDATE statement instead.

---

```
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ProjectTasks SET Name=@Name, Description=@Description " +
        "WHERE TaskID=@TaskID; " +
    "SELECT TOP 1 TaskID FROM ProjectTasks ORDER BY TaskID DESC;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescription.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());

    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Resource_Materials SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Equipments SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Vehicles SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0; " +
                        "UPDATE Resource_Contractors SET TaskID=@TaskID WHERE TaskID=0;";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Helper.AddLog("1", "Add", "Assigned Resources to Task");
    Response.Redirect("~/Projects/Default.aspx");
```